# Selecting mysql info

Tags: mysql

i want to select all notice for my friends on same id row

but am getting error that my query is syntax means the query has problem

i will appreciate for help

```
TABLE USER

id  acc   name
1   4455   jo
2   8945   pa
3   6544   lee


TABLE FRIENDS

id   acc    friend
1    4455   6544
2    6544   8945


TABLE NOTIC

id  acc    info
1  4455    hey pals
2  8945    hey pa
```

Query

```
snd.acc, snd.name, m.info FROM 
NOTIC as m 
JOIN USER as snd ON snd.acc = m.acc WHERE snd.acc IN (SELECT acc, friend FROM FRIENDS WHERE acc = '4455' OR friend = '4455')
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you want.

Comment: i want to select and return notics to friends i have in NOTIC table where my acc in table friends eq to acc colum or friend colum

Comment: _but am getting error_ What error are you getting?

Comment: The subquery used in `WHERE IN` has to return just one column to match against `snd.acc`

Comment: You need to modify _WHERE snd.acc IN (SELECT acc, friend FROM_ to **WHERE snd.acc IN (SELECT acc FROM**

Answer (score 0):

When you use `WHERE column in (subquery)`, the subquery can only return one column.

If you want to return both `acc` and `friend` depending on whether the given ID is the friend or account, use a `UNION` subquery.

```
WHERE acc in (
    SELECT acc FROM friends WHERE friend = '4455'
    UNION
    SELECT friend FROM friends WHERE acc = '4455'
)
```

Comment: when i try this it works but returning multiple same data according to friends or acc i have in table friends ` snd.acc, snd.name, m.info FROM 
NOTIC as m 
JOIN USER as snd ON snd.acc = m.acc WHERE snd.acc IN (SELECT acc FROM FRIENDS WHERE acc = '4455' OR friend = '4455')`

Comment: The only friend of 4455 is 6544 lee. There are no notices for acc = 6544, so the result is empty.